# How can Davros change chairs?

Tags: doctor-who

Davros has had 3 chairs (the black one from the 4th doctor era, the white one from the 7th doctor era, the one since the time war). If Davros can't rise from his chair how can he change chairs?

Comment: Well, he'd get a lift, either rigging one himself, or getting his guards to do it.  You may as well be asking how anyone without legs does the same.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason to think that Davros can change his chair on his own.  He cannot survive on his own for more than a brief time.  However, he has daleks to help him make the transition.

With today's technology, surgeons can perform heart transplants; the transplants, as well as other kinds of open heart surgery, entail sending the patient's blood through a heart-lung machine, which pumps and oxygenates it.  The daleks have super-advanced technology, far beyond what we have today on Earth.  There is no reason to doubt that they could temporarily provide Davros with his necessary life support while he is moved from one chair hookup to another.